# Empty field in Activeadmin resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm using  `gem  'activeadmin'` in my project.
here is `app\admin\person.rb` file

```
ActiveAdmin.register Person do

  permit_params :name, :gender, :age, :address
  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :image do
        image_tag(person.image.url)
      end
      row :name
      row :gender
      row :age
      row :address
    end
  end
end
```

how can I stop showing empty field in Activeadmin resource view. Here is an image of view.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `if statement` on the object.
In `app\admin\person.rb` file.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Person do

  permit_params :name, :gender, :age, :address, :image
  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :image if offender.image? do
        image_tag(person.image.url)
      end
      row(:name) if person.name?
      row(:gender) if person.gender?
      row(:age) if person.age?
      row(:address) if person.address?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[`presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) returns an object or nil if it's empty. Try:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Person do

  permit_params :name, :gender, :age, :address
  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :image { image_tag(person.image.url) }
      row(:name).presence
      row(:gender).presence
      row(:age).presence
      row(:address).presence
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. OP is trying to hide the row if the value is nil, not if the row itself is nil